# Как разместить текст равномерно по строке в HTML?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно равномерно разместить следующие данные на одной строке:

`'27.07.2017', 'USD: 59,91', 'Euro: 69,68', 'Brent: 50,91', 'Вы вошли как Guido'`.

Курсы валют и нефти должны быть по середине. Для этого я использовал просто тег `<pre>` безо всяких стилей, с десятками пробелов.

Comment: Что значит равномерно? Равномерно относительно чего?

Comment: Дата слева, авторизация справа, все остальное в центре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `float` в стилях, чтобы "раскидать" нужные блоки слева и справа, оставив всё остальное по центру:

```html
<p style="text-align: center">
  <span style="float: left">27.07.2017</span>
  <span>USD: 59,91</span>
  <span>Euro: 69,68</span>
  <span>Brent: 50,91</span>
  <span style="float: right">Вы вошли как Guido</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с флексбоксами

```css
.flex {
display:flex;
text-align:center;
}
.flex * {
flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.flex *:first-child {
text-align:left;
}
.flex *:last-child {
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<div>27.07.2017</div>
<div>USD: 59,91, Euro: 69,68, Brent: 50,91</div>
<div>Вы вошли как Guido</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать flexbox. И для детей задавать `margin` `auto` для перемещения блоков на максимальное расстояние. Хотя я бы советовал не полагаться на номера блоков в разметке, а добавлять соответствующие классы. Демонстрация:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

/* второй блок и последний сместить максильно вправа */
.flex > :nth-child(2),
.flex > :last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* остальные блоки отодвинуть на 10px вправа */
.flex > :not(:nth-child(2)),
.flex > :not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex__item">27.07.2017</div>
  <div class="flex__item">USD: 59,91</div>
  <div class="flex__item">Euro: 69,68</div>
  <div class="flex__item">Brent: 50,91</div>
  <div class="flex__item">Вы вошли как Guido</div>
</div>
```